# how i will identified last row number of xls sheet while reading xls large sheet using SheetContentsHandler poi api

Tags: apache-poi

how i will identified last row number of xls sheet while reading xls sheet using `SheetContentsHandler` poi api.

Any event that can help to identifies last row number in `SheetContentsHandler`.

Comment: Have your code track the "current" row, and fire off some logic when parsing has completed / a new sheet starts?

Comment: for example am process 1007 records . i have define batch size of 1000. in

Comment: for example am process 1007 records . i have define batch size of 1000 and adding data object in list in "endrow " method and check the size of list to 1000 and clear list after of 1000 records . but unable to handle last 7 records because doest know the last record of sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I have get remaining data list when sheet parsing is completed.

Answer (score 1):

You probably will need to look for the largest row-number in your implementation of the `SheetContentsHandler` to get this:

```
public class Handler implements SheetContentsHandler {
    int maxRow = 0;

    @Override
    void startRow(int rowNum) {
        maxRow = Math.max(rowNum, maxRow);
    }
    ...
```

After you use this class for streaming the file, `maxRow` will contain the last row-number in the file.

Comment: or example am process 1007 records . i have define batch size of 1000 and adding data object in list in "endrow " method and check the size of list to 1000 and clear list after of 1000 records . but unable to handle last 7 records because doest know the last record of sheet

Comment: how can find last row of xls sheet when reading using SheetContentsHandler one by one row ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I have get remaining data list when sheet parsing is completed.